# whats wrong with the below code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
class A {

  let color = 'red';


  let handleClick = () => {}

  let handleLongClick = function() {}
}

console.log('done');
```

I'm trying to run this code in http://jsbin.com/bopiqizaka/edit?js,console. I was expecting it to print `done`. [image: see the red mark in the image] but it's not. Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't just put anything you want in the body of a class. All you can put are methods and accessors.

Comment: Please go read the very basics of how a `class` definition works.  You've missed the very first few steps in what it is and how it works.  There's really no reason for us to cover that here as there are literally thousands of tutorials on the web and every single place you find the `class` keyword described with examples of code, it would show you the proper usage.  Voting to close as "too broad".  No need to reteach a topic that is covered pretty much everywhere you could look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use variables (`let`, `var`, `const`) within classes like that. 
You need to write a `constructor` and within the `constructor`, you can define what attributes the class should have, e. g. `color`.

For methods, you simply write the methods name (without `function` or the ES6 syntax).

```js
class A {

  constructor() {
    this.color = "red";
  }

  handleClick() {}

  handleLongClick() {}


};

console.log('done');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'let' for variable declaration inside class. If you want to have instance variables then use constructor and define methods as shown in following example.

```
    class A {

  constructor(){
    this.color = "red";
  }

  handleClick(){}

  handleLongClick(){}


};

console.log('done');
```